# Adobe Flash Builder 4: Fade Effect with Auto Hide after Countdown?

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe, builder

In a Flex Project, whenever there's an error, I fill in the error data into a hidden **TextInput** then show the control to the user. I want to make it so that after showing the **TextInput**, it will automatically hide itself after some time with a fade effect. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for such cases i use a custom `MotionCreator` class. There are a lot of tweeners in the web